# Carriage return \r in bash terminal printing from perl script causing freeze

Tags: linux, perl, bash

I'm printing progress from a perl script in bash using Ubuntu 12.04. When I use this:

```
foreach my $filename (sort @files) {
    print "Processing $filename...\n";
```

it prints each progress line with a gap of ~2 secs between each print, and that's fine. But there's a good few files, so it's noisy. I tried to use this instead:

```
print "\rProcessing $filename...";
```

but now I get no output at all until the script has gotten to the last file, and then that's the only print statement that I see (the last one). Incidentally, I don't care about erasing the previously printed statement because each will be exactly the same length.

However, I can do `seq 1 1000000 | while read i; do echo -en "\r$i"; done` in bash and it works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try unbuffered output in your perl script,

```
$| = 1;
```

Comment: Nice one, that was quick!

Answer (score 2):

**You are [Suffering from Buffering](http://perl.plover.com/FAQs/Buffering.html)**.  The link provided takes you to an excellent article from The Perl Journal circa 1998 from Marc Jason Dominus (the author of Higher-Order Perl).  The article may be over a decade old, but the topic is as relevant today as it was when he wrote it.

As mpapec suggested the `$| = 1;` technique. I would add to it that in the predominant thinking of the Perl community seems to be that `$| = 1` is preferable over `$|++` simply because it is clearer in its meaning.  I know, autoincrement is pretty simple too, but does everyone who will ever look at your code know `$|`'s behavior when `++` or `--` are applied (without looking it up in [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html)).  I happen to also prefer to localize any modification of Perl's "special variables" so that the effects are not washing over into other portions of code that may not play nice with a particular change to default Perl behavior.